# How to eliminate water in crawlspace

Tags: repair, crawlspace

I would like to install 4" perforated drain pipe along the footer on the inside of a crawlspace. The bottom of the footer is at the height of the existing crawlspace floor. Should I lay the pipe along the footer? I'm thinking I would have to lay a 2" bed of gravel then the pipe and then raise the height of the floor to the height of the top of the footer? If this seems logical, what would you suggest I use for fill? (gravel/dirt/sand)
i am open to any suggestions to remedy the standing water in the crawlspace.
thank you for your reply !!

Answer (score 1):

Often times the best location to place the drain lines along a footing is on the outside of the building structure. This allows collection of the water before it enters the area under the building. It also allows trenching away from the building toward a drain field so there is a place for the collected water to go.

If you do put the piping inside the footing perimeter you may need to also install a sump pit at the down flow end of the pipes. Then a sump pump is installed to move the water to a drain or to pump it outside and away from the building structure.

Comment: Thanks Michael  I can not do a French drain on outside due to a concrete porch and paving. There presently is a sump pump (non functional)in the crawlspace. That aside, does what I planned to do sound logical? The pump pit is there, the water does not make it's way to the pit. my intent was to install perforated DWV and surround with 2B gravel. The problem is that the existing grade of the crawlspace floor is at the same height as the bottom of the footing... almost as though the footing was poured and no back fill on the inside of the foundation wall. (hopefully you can envision this)

Comment: It is a little odd that a hole is dug for the crawl space and the footings are not dug deeper at the perimeter than the nominal base of the crawl space hole. But I suppose it is not unheard of as demonstrated by your case.

Comment: I see no real issue of you putting the piping that you propose along the inside of the footings. You probably want to make it all have a certain slope from one high point to a single lowest point where the sump and pump would be located. Such location may be different than the existing hole location of the old sump pit due to original poor design.

Comment: Yes, I will slope piping 1/4" per 10 feet. What would you suggest I use to fill the center of the space to bring it up to the level of the pipe that I will install ? 2B washed gravel ? My feeling is that I will need to raise the central part of the space to keep the pipe in place.

Comment: You could put gravel in side the area of the crawl space. That would definitely be an aid to keeping the pipe in place by the footing and raise the crawl space "floor" up to hopefully be a dry surface. Several questions arise. Is the crawl space floor all currently level? Does adding 4 - 6 inches of gravel in there make the crawl space inaccessible due to the now reduced head clearance? How much does the outside ground level rise above the top of the footing? Do you have a decent means of getting that much gravel into the crawl space (sounds like a big task)?